# Is there a known way of producing forecasts with reasonable fit and residuals that are at least independent, & ideally negatively correlated?

Tags: forecasting, residuals, independence, ensemble-learning

I am trying to do some forecasts. I have produced multiple forecasts by a variety of methods. All of the forecasts I have generated so far have residuals that are strongly positively correlated.I would like to produce forecasts that have residuals that are, at a minimum, independent, and ideally negatively correlated. Are there known procedures for selecting forecasting methods for which the residuals have either of these properties? The benefits for ensemble forecasting
are, I think, obvious.

Comment: Interesting question, though I have my doubts that *intentionally* doing this would have benefits for ensemble forecasting. A possibility might be to use a model with relevant predictors vs. one that does not include predictors, which will therefore be intentionally biased whenever the predictors have an impact. The residuals might then be negatively correlated. In an ensemble, this would have a similar result to regularizing the predictor impact towards zero... so one could do that in the first place.

Comment: The only way I can see doing that is to have utterly useless forecasts: make them *iid* random variables.

Comment: What is the setting? Single dependent variable with values real $-\infty\dots\infty$ and normally distributed errors? ARIMA type model? You should be able to cast it into multivariate normal distribution problem and use something like diagonalisation to enforce independence of residuals.

Comment: Please tell us the meaning of "strongly positively correlated."  Is that an assertion about a probability model you have for the data, or is it a description?  If it is, and you have a collection of univariate residuals (one for each method), how do you measure their correlation?  In what sense do you use the term "independent," given these methods all apply to the *same* data and therefore (in the sense of probability) cannot possibly be independent?